# 2 Actions For Same Route in Asp.Net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have route defined as

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Company", // Route name
            "Company/{companyname}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Company", action = "CompanyDetail", companyname = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Now the problem is that i have made this route if now i made any request to company controller and pass a parameter it goes to `CompanyDetail` method , but in one condition i dont want to send to this method i want to send the control to another action `CallCompany`  . How to solve this and note i also need to run both type of request .

Comment: can you provide the url which should go to CallCompany action

Comment: /Company/Foo    ...   here Foo is the parameter and i want it to go to /Company/CallCompany but due to default Route it goes to /Company/CompanyDetail

Comment: can you show us all your routes? also, what is that "one condition" on which you don't want to send to this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood your question, you want to realise the following behavior:

There is as set of company names (for example, "test") and they correspond with URL

yourhost/Company/test

They should be routed to CallCompany.

The other URL (such as yourhost/Company/another_company) should be routed to CompanyDetail.

I think, that the best way is to do redirect in CompanyDetail method

```
    public ActionResult CallCompany(string companyname)
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult CompanyDetail(string companyname)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> myCompanies = GetSpecialCompany();
        if (myCompanies.Contains(companyname))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("CallCompany", new { companyname = companyname });
        }
        return View();
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> GetSpecialCompany()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can set it in your controller method:

```cs
public ActionResult CompanyDetail(string companyname)
{
    if (condition)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("ActionName", new { companyname = companyname});
    }
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should probabaly look into mvc [route constraints](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs). that would enable you to forward request on the simillar url to different action depending uopn different parameters which you can programatically set.
for example

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Product",
    "Product/{productId}",
    new {controller="Product", action="Details"},
    new {productId = @"\d+" }
 );
```

this would only go to controller:Product and action Details in product id is an int
in your case you will have to define the pattern in regex for which request should go to one route and place the second route next to this
so automatically every request which dosent fit the constraint for this route will be handeled by the next one.